# effective and pretty string conditions in Java

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements

I have a question about code style:

Let's assume i have a String containing some information (like "Information1" or "Information2"). Based on this i want to create objects with a factory. Obviously i could write something like this:

```
if(string.equals("Information1")){
  Factory.createInformation1Object();
}
if(string.equals("Information2")){
  Factory.createInformation2Object();
}
if(string.equals("Information3")){
  Factory.createInformation3Object();
}
```

Now i was wondering if there is a better (and prettier) way to do this. I really like the multiple dispatch idea of the visitor pattern, but i cant see a way to apply this easily to this particular problem.

Comment: you could probably use a regex like "information[0-9]" with a matcher ? But I don't better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Create an abstract `Factory` class [or interface], and classes that extends it: `MyObject1Factory`, `MyObject2Factory`, ...

On preprocessing, populate a `Map<String,Factory>` from a `String` to the coresponding `Factory` instance, this is done only once in your application.

When you need to create a new instance - invoke `map.get(string).create()` to create the relevant object, of the relevant type.

**Edit: Small example with code:**

Your classes are:

```
public static class MyBase { 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Base";
    }
}
public static class Class1 extends MyBase { 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Class1";
    }
}
public static class Class2 extends MyBase { 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Class2";
    }
}
```

And your factories will be:

```
public static abstract class MyFactory {
    public abstract MyBase build();
}
public static class MyFactory1 extends MyFactory {
    @Override
    public Class1 build() {
        return new Class1();
    }
}
public static class MyFactory2 extends MyFactory {
    @Override
    public Class2 build() {
        return new Class2();
    }
}
```

populate a map **only once** in the program lifetime:

```
    Map<String,MyFactory> map = new HashMap<String, Test.MyFactory>();
    map.put("class1", new MyFactory1());
    map.put("class2", new MyFactory2());
```

and when you need a new object, invoke with:

```
    MyBase obj = map.get(s).build();
    System.out.println(obj);
```

(*) Note: The static keyword for classes are here because I created them as inner classes - of course you need to ommit it if it is not your case....

Answer (score 2):

In Java 7 you can now use strings in switch statements.

Note that your code isn't directly analagous to a switch statement because it's theoretically possible for all three factory methods to be called just by looking at the structure of the code (e.g. no `else` statements). But in practice that can't happen because `string` can't simultaneously have all three values.

Comment: would using a switch statement really be any better in terms of readability and usability? I would still have a massive amount of code in one place, except i have `case`s instead of `if`s

Comment: Depends on exactly what you were asking! I interpreted the question as being about the string handling (since that's what the subject implied), whereas others have interpreted it as being about the overall design, patterns, etc.

Comment: In other words, from a design perspective, no, it doesn't materially improve matters.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer functional and readable. :-) If string is null and calling its method will definitely throw NPE, consider the following instead,

```
"Information1".equals(strings)
```

Perhaps Information1, Information2, and Information3 can be put as class static variable so it could be easily reference and prevent human typo error.

Comment: Another new nick I got, today!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` statement newly in Java 7. [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use switch-case, because of the unnesessery checks if first or second check is true.
In default section you could place other activity like exception throwing or so on.